# Full explanation of the 49 Sefirot combinations?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, sefirat-ha-omer, middos-character-traits, emotions, sefirot-attributes

I am looking for a good source that explains the 49 middot-sefirot combinations.

Especially as they manifest as emotions, and ideally explained from "chametz" to "matza", i.e. the שְׂאוֹר שֶׁבָּעִיסָּה ("yeast in the dough"/self-centered version), and the kosher, correct versions of how these emotions are produced, felt and expressed in a relationship?

Otherwise, I'd be happy to receive absolutely any listing + explanation of them, no matter what the focus, no matter if contemporary or ancient.

Currently, I have access to R' Shlomo Katz's sefira videos, R' Yaakov Klein's images for sefira, and Journey of Togetherness - 49 Steps to Transforming a Family by Sarah Hermelin

Comment: https://mosaicapress.com/product/sefiros/ People seem to like this, although I've never read it myself

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/276672/jewish/Daily-Spiritual-Guide.htm

Comment: Looks to me like the original source is Pri Etz Chaim, Shaar Sefirat haomer, chapter 5

Comment: @MeirLuria what specifically is originally sourced there?

Comment: The practice of connecting the sefirot to the omer

Comment: @MeirLuria interesting. I did put a sefira tag, but I am not trying to focus this around sefirat haomer, but rather try to identify conceptually what each of the 49 root combinations are, in terms of emotion/character. Nun shaarei bina is the shoresh of this and goes back to Sinai

Answer (score 1):

Many years ago I read a short book called וספרתם לכם, which takes you through 49 days and their corresponding sefirot. Although it wasn't significantly in depth, it did relate to each sefirah in turn and gave some practical advice on how to actualise a particular aspect/middah of that day.

I'm not sure if there's a version in English.